# Sort columns in Excel sheet: Same values into same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, phpexcel, excel-2007

I've exported a JSON file into an Excel file where I have hundreds of dates with specific characteristics. However, there is some missing data, consequently

| User | date/0 | property 1/0 | property 2/0 | property 3/0 | date/1 | property 1/1 | property 2/1 | property 3/1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | date 1 | ... | ... | ... | date 2 | ... | ... | ... |
| User 2 | date 1 | ... | ... | ... | date 3 | ... | ... | ... |
| User 3 | date 2 | ... | ... | ... | date 4 | ... | ... | ... |

What I would want to have would be the following:

| User | date 1 | property 1 date 1 | property 2 date 1 | property 3 date 1 | date 2 | property 1 date 2 | property 2 date 2 | property 3 date 2 | date 3 | property 1 date 3 | property 2 date 3 | property 3 date 3 | date 4 | property 1 date 4 | property 2 date 4 | property 3 date 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | date 1 | ... | ... | ... | date 2 | ... | ... | ... | date 3 |  |  |  | date 4 |  |  |  |
| User 2 | date 1 | ... | ... | ... | date 2 |  |  |  | date 3 | ... | ... | ... | date 4 |  |  |  |
| User 3 | date 1 |  |  |  | date 2 |  |  |  | date 3 | ... | ... | ... | date 4 | ... | ... | ... |

Can you help me in transforming my table this way?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try index match function.

Comment: in ur trials.. where did u stuck at?